# Can't restore canvas to earlier state

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I want to be able to draw a line and then undo that. The restore/save methods don't seem to work. What i expect from the following code is to have a blank view, because, just after drawing a line, we restore the canvas to the state where nothing was painted. However, the end result is a line on the screen, which means the restoration didn't work.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.save();
    canvas.drawLine(100, 0, 100, screenWidth, paint);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

I looked at others related posts, but they used paths and not the method drawLine.
Could anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong or what an alternative might be ?

Comment: Maybe you should paste screenshot and sample image what you expected for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

The key is you have to save the what are you "painting" and later access to the array with the lines or elements you draw.

```
public void onClickUndo () {  
    if (paths.size()>0) 
    {  
       undonePaths.add(paths.remove(paths.size()-1));
       invalidate();
     } 
    else 
    { 

    } 
     //msg to the user  
}
```